# Term Store - Stakeholders

Tags: term-store, email-notification

This field's description says : This information is used to track people and groups in the organization that should be notified before major changes are made to the term set. You can enter multiple users or groups.

I have placed emails of people in this box and deleted terms, modified terms and the 'stakeholders' never received anything. I was thinking about an email to tell you a term has been created/deleted/edited.

What is the use of this box? what it is supposed to do?

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the snip of this . I think I can help you out here but just need a snip of this first.

Comment: added. The field requires just one or more users, as displayed in the image.The user never received any sort of notification via email

Comment: Stakeholders are those users who receive e-mail notification when the term set owner or term store administrator makes changes to the term set. Imagine you have a body of people who want to monitor the evolution of terms for a given term set—these people would be the stakeholders. Check if submission policy is opened and try to make changes and see if you get any emails .

Comment: so it works only when submission policy is opened and not when it is closed and Term set managers are adding terms?

Comment: Yes, that's what i noticed

Comment: I have added myself as stakeholder and added a new term, from the interface of the end user, not from the term store and I had no email. Does it need hours or days to come active?

Comment: Nops, you should have received an email . Is your SMTP server set up and configured to be used in SharePoint ?

Comment: we receive emails in every other situation from sharepoint such as alerts. Also i am using SP online, we do not have to configure SMTP

Comment: I tested it again and it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Point 1:**

About `submission policy`,

> We can also set the Submission Policy which dictates whether we allow
>   users to contribute to the Term Set (commonly referred to folksonomy) or restrict it to > only metadata managers (Taxonomy).

Submission policy has nothing to do with Stakeholders.

**Point 2:**

[How to organize Metadata in the SharePoint Term Store](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-organize-metadata-in-the-sharepoint-term-store/)

> Please note that though Term sets have Owner and Stakeholder fields as
>   well, they do not control security for the given term set. Once again,
>   security for term sets is controlled at the group (folder level).

Security has nothing to do with the field(Owner and Stakeholders).

**Point 3:**

[Managed metadata roles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/assign-roles-and-permissions-to-manage-term-sets#managed-metadata-roles)

> When you set up a term set, you can designate a group or a person as
>   an Owner, Contact, or Stakeholders for the term set. These labels do
>   not grant any specific permission to work with the term set. Instead,
>   they provide a useful way to track the business owners or stakeholders
>   for a term set.

Only this Information available for Stakeholders, that s/he able to track it. How? didn't mention.

**Point 4:**

[Creating new Term Sets In SharePoint 2013](https://blog.navantis.com/creating-new-term-sets-in-sharepoint-2013/)

> users assigned as Stakeholders will be notified when the Term Set
>   changes

This used to happen in SharePoint 2013 and earlier versions.

**Point 5(Practical):**

I created a term set, assign group managers and contributor at the group level, assign Owner and Stakeholder at Term Set Level, but nothing happens.

1. Performed CRUD on Term Set using Owner and then using Contributor
2. Changed Properties of Term Set using the owner

I got no email notification. Please! check Screenshots.

[image]

[image]

**Point 6:**

After this much operation, what major changes SharePoint platform talking about, I don't know.

> This information is used to track people and groups in the
>   organization that should be notified before major changes are made to
>   the term set.

**Solution 1:**

If it's really required for you. Then you can create a Powershell script which will retrieve all term sets created or modified today and send an email notification to stakeholders. This Powershell script executes on a daily basis.

**Conclusion:**

1. I think it had only worked in SharePoint 2013 and versions before it.
   You can generate a Support ticket to Microsoft.
2. No configuration of `SMTP` and `Exchange` required in SharePoint
   online.
3. Just for Information, `Alert Me` operation will work in SharePoint
   online when adding a new list or library into SharePoint.

**Update: 17 Sep 2019**

I talk to Microsoft support and in reply, they provide me a text which is mentioned in Point 3.

> Instead, they provide a useful way to track the business owners or
>   stakeholders for a term set.

Therefore the user who wants to make changes in the term set, first s/he will discuss with owner and stakeholders. This is the process in SharePoint Online, That's all.

Again, in the SharePoint server, they will notify when changes are made in term set but not in SharePoint Online.